# Polygon Z Ordering

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, 2d, rendering

I am currently trying to write a 2D only 3D "renderer" that uses polygons only.

Before rendering, I order the polygons by calculating one Z value as following:

```
double z = (v1.getZ()+v2.getZ()+v3.getZ());
```

My polygons consist of each three vectors (X,Y,Z)

Then I sort the polygons so I then can use the painters algorithm approach:

```
int i = 0;
for (Poly polygon : polyZSort) {
    if(polygon.getRealZ()>z) {
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
polyZSort.add(i, polygon);
```

The rendering then is as simple as:

```
for (Poly poly : polyZSort) {
    OVector v1 = poly.getV1();
    v1 = form.doTransform(v1);
    OVector v2 = poly.getV2();
    v2 = form.doTransform(v2);
    OVector v3 = poly.getV3();
    v3 = form.doTransform(v3);
                
    g2d.setColor(poly.getColor());

    Polygon pl = new Polygon();
    pl.addPoint(getX(v1.getX()),getY(v1.getY()));   
    pl.addPoint(getX(v2.getX()),getY(v2.getY()));   
    pl.addPoint(getX(v3.getX()),getY(v3.getY()));
                

    g2d.fillPolygon(pl);    

    // black border line
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2d.drawLine(
        getX(v1.getX()), 
        getY(v1.getY()), 
        getX(v2.getX()), 
        getY(v2.getY())
    );
                
    g2d.drawLine(
        getX(v2.getX()), 
        getY(v2.getY()), 
        getX(v3.getX()), 
        getY(v3.getY())
    );
                
    g2d.drawLine(
        getX(v3.getX()), 
        getY(v3.getY()), 
        getX(v1.getX()), 
        getY(v1.getY())
    );                          
}
```

This works, even with multiple cubes (but only most of the time):
[image: works]

However in certain positions, the ordering seems to be wrong:
[image]

Does anybody know where the problem may be?
Here a video of the "glitch" https://vimeo.com/552355610

Comment: I’m not sure I understand how your sorting code is supposed to work.  Perhaps you want `polyZsort.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Poly::getRealZ))` instead?

Comment: Hi @VGR
It takes all polygons, sorts them by their Z value and then fills it in order into the new list.
Your code is equivalent - i just used it instead of my ugly sort.
I assume the problem is, that interpolating the Z value for the whole polygon by taking the geometrical middles Z value isn't sufficient.

Comment: Hi @Spektre
Thank you for confirming my assumption. So i project to 2D while still knowing their Z values. What exactly do you mean by dissect?  I can write the code if they overlap, but then what? :)
Id be very grateful for any pseudo code or a link to read on this topic. 

Yeah I doubt this will scale, its just out of curiosities sake.

Cheers

Comment: @ozzi- have converted comment into answer  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing important steps ... This is how it should be done:

1. **input is list of 3D triangles, output is list of 3D triangles**

   The output list is empty at start
2. **"2D" screen project each processed triangle and leave it with original z values**

   so its still 3D , but `x,y` are screen positions and z is "original" `z` value in camera coordinate system.
3. **check each processed triangle after projection if it intersects any triangle already in output list.**

   If no intersection occurs then simply add this triangle to output list as is.

   if it does intersect you need to re-triangulate all intersected and new triangle so no intersections occur. And add these new triangle(s) to output list (while removing the original intersecting triangles from output list).

   Here exampel of 2 overlaping triangles:

   [image: retriangulation]

   as you can see it can create quite a lot of new triangles and usually new triangle intersects more than just one triangle so you need to do this recursively for each triangle of the overlapped parts or create a list of all intersecting triangles first and retriangulate them at once ...
4. **after whole scene is processed Z sort the output list by mid point z value**

   this step you already got.
5. **render the sorted output list using 2D triangle rendering**

   this step you already got.

As you can see you need a buffer of size depending on number of triangles in scene and overlaps. Also this method is very complicated (and not very good choice for rookie programmers) and usable only for very simple scenes. For more complex ones is much easier and faster to use Z buffer. However that one require along with the buffer itself also 3D rendering of triangle (so one more interpolation and per pixel condition). As you can see its `O(1)` instead of the `O(n.log(n))` for z sort.

Comment: Funny enough, I refactored my code for each polygon to use 4 points instead of 3 (meaning one side of the cube now consists of one polygon instead of 2 triangles) and the crude z sort works just fine.

Comment: @ozzi- Yes as with quads there is much less conflicts between mid point depth and true depth in overlapped parts ... btw In case you got only convex meshes you could do something else... use polygon winding to remove back faces and use z sort only on per object maner ... that is how it was faked in old 3D games like Elite. And I think freespace engine is exploiting that too